# XSLT - boolean true if attribute value character length greater than 10

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I attempted this to count the total characters of my title attribute value, but it didn't seem to evaluate as I intended it to:

```
<xsl:if test="count(@title)>10">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">double-line</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

I also tried to append /text() to @title. It looks like I'm still off. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want the string-length function:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(@title) &gt; 10">
```

Comment: Er - gt and lt instead of the literal?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's `string-length()` you are after.